# Erorrs when creating a new Aurelia CLI 1.3.0 project

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to create a new project using the instructions from the official page of the Aurelia CLI https://github.com/aurelia/cli but every time when I run `au-new` I get the following error. I'm using Windows 10 x64.

[image: Aurelia CLI bug]

Comment: You tried running as admin?

Comment: are you running this command behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: @avrahamcool turned off all the settings in the proxy and it started to work. Thank you for your support!